# Apache Beanutils, are there other jars out there that do Bean reflection?

Tags: reflection, jar, osgi, javabeans, bundle

I am having trouble with OSGI and a missing constraint exception with Apache's commons-beanutils-1.8.3. I can't figure it out and I was wondering if there is another Bean reflection jar out there so I can call set and get property on beans with reflection.

Comment: Maybe there is but why give up so easily? If you post the error messages then somebody can probably help.

Comment: What is this "bean reflection" you are talking 'bout? I would be interested to find out the reason for using something like this (I'm curious).